# Is PPM format industry standard?

Tags: bitmap, pixel, ppm

I am trying to understand at a fundamental level how the pixel data for images and videos are generated. I came across the use of the [PPM](https://www.scratchapixel.com) protocol where each value of the pixel (RGB) is written in the file. Is this the protocol UI libraries use? For example, when creating a `CGRect` in iOS, at the very bottom of the chain there has to be some interface that tells the drivers to define each pixel RGB value. Is PPM protocol used in production? Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: I don't believe it's an industry standard for UI data on any platform. It was initially called **PBM Plus** then **NetPBM** and was designed as the least common denominator to which all images could be reduced so that if there were N formats you didn't need NxN converters, just 2N... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm

Comment: Gotcha - yeah I remember reading about it being the starting point for all image types. But for example, let's a laser projector that is going to display an image of a landscape. The laser (assume its a combo of RGB lasers) will have to display a single pixel until it's created the image. In order to do so, each pixel needs to be defined with a value so the laser knows "at this coordinate, display this RGB value". Seems like the PPM file does exactly that.